# change the backgroundColor of progress bar in Java Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, colors, jprogressbar, nimbus

I am a newbie in Java, I need changing the background Color of a progress bar, but really I don't know how to do  this
I have a progress bar called "barrita"
I am using Linux Ubuntu and Java 8 and I am using the palette of Swing

```
package loginprogressbar;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author fernando
 */
public class Inicio extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Timer tiempo;
    int contador;
    public static final int TWO_SECOND = 2;

    class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            contador += 1;
            barrita.setValue(contador);
            if (contador == 100) {
                tiempo.stop();
                esconder();
                Menu1 m1 = new Menu1();
                m1.setVisible(true);
                m1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }

        }

    }

    public void esconder() {
        this.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void activar() {
        tiempo.start();
    }

    public Inicio() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        barrita.setVisible(false);

    }

    public void inicionSesion() {
        String usuario = panel2.getText();
        String password = (String.valueOf(txtPassword.getText()));
        if (usuario.equals("fernando") && password.compareTo("12345") == 0) {
            barrita.setVisible(true);
            contador = -1;
            barrita.setValue(0);
            barrita.setStringPainted(true);
            tiempo = new Timer(TWO_SECOND, new TimerListener());
            activar();

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al ingresar usuario o contraseña incorrecta");
            panel2.setText("");
            txtPassword.setText("");
            panel2.requestFocus();

        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        panel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        panel2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtPassword = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        btnEntrar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        barrita = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        panel1.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                panel1KeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        panel2.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                panel2KeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Nombre");

        jLabel2.setText("Contraseña");

        txtPassword.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txtPasswordKeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnEntrar.setText("Ingresar");
        btnEntrar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnEntrarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout panel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel1);
        panel1.setLayout(panel1Layout);
        panel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, panel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnEntrar)
                .addGap(83, 83, 83))
            .addGroup(panel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(58, 58, 58)
                .addGroup(panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(panel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(barrita, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(panel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(txtPassword)
                            .addComponent(panel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 130, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGap(113, 113, 113))))
        );
        panel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(panel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                .addGroup(panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(panel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addGroup(panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(txtPassword, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(barrita, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(btnEntrar)
                .addContainerGap(93, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        getContentPane().add(panel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 400, 300));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void panel1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                  
        if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            inicionSesion();
        }
    }                                 

    private void btnEntrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        inicionSesion();  // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void txtPasswordKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
        if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            btnEntrar.requestFocus();
        }
    }                                      

    private void panel2KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                  

        if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            txtPassword.requestFocus();
        }
    }                                 

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Inicio().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar barrita;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnEntrar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel panel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField panel2;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField txtPassword;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Write a look and feel delegate for the progress bar :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change JProgressBar color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773978/how-to-change-jprogressbar-color)

Comment: Nimbus allows you to customise the look and feel, although it's a little complicated.  Windows and MacOS L&F's will ignore the `UIManager` properties and do there own thing, don't know about Linux.  Only the Metal L&F will honor the `UIManager` properties. For Nimbus, you can have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379251/change-ui-lookup-for-progressbar-swing-in-nimbus-theme/24379428#24379428)