# Working with progressbar

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jprogressbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nice looking progress bar in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884297/nice-looking-progress-bar-in-java)

I use `setBackground` and `setForeground` to set the color of a `JProgressBar` but they didn't work, the color remain Orange. I can't change it.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: See also the approach suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8884297/230513).

Answer (score 2):

It's likely due to your installed look-and-feel. Does this help: [change-colors-for-jprogressbar-with-nimbus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174420/change-colors-for-jprogressbar-with-nimbus)

Comment: how to work with change-colors-for-jprogressbar-with-nimbus,plz tell

Comment: Are you using Nimbus look-and-feel? If so, the source-code in the answer should help. If not, please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), as Andrew Thompson suggests.