# JProgressbar: how to change colour based on progress?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, colors, jprogressbar

Is it possible to be able to change the bar colour depending on the value of the progress? I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
percentUsed = (int)(((float) used / (float) max) * BAR_PERCENTAGE);
      if (percentUsed >= ORANGE_THRESHOLD &&  percentUsed < RED_THRESHOLD) {
        if (!m_orangeIndicator) {
          LOG.warn(String.format("Memory usage exceeds %d percent.", ORANGE_THRESHOLD));
          m_orangeIndicator = true;
        }
        colour = Color.ORANGE;
        m_redIndicator = false;
      }
      else if (percentUsed >= RED_THRESHOLD) {
        if (!m_redIndicator) {
          LOG.warn(String.format("Memory usage exceeds %d percent.", RED_THRESHOLD));
          m_orangeIndicator = true;
          m_redIndicator = true;
        }
        colour = Color.RED;
      }
      else {
        m_orangeIndicator = false;
        m_redIndicator = false;
        colour = Color.GREEN;
      }
      m_memUsageBar.setForeground(colour);
      m_memUsageBar.setValue(percentUsed);
      m_memUsageBar.updateUI();
```

I am guessing it is not a trivial thing to do because JProgressbar is not meant to be used that way... But is it possible or are there alternatives?

Comment: First thing that pops out is - don't call `updateUI`. This doesn't have anything (directly) to do with requesting repaints. Use `invalidate` and `repaint` instead.

Comment: Yeah the `updateUI` part was me grasping at straws. I tried invalidate and repaint but no changes were seen.

Comment: It appears that the Windows L&F ignores the background and foreground settings, which is rather annoying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help but by trial and error I found a way to get the colour changing with using my existing code.

I am not sure if its the quirk of JPrgressbar but if call do the following call the foreground bar colour can be changed dynamically with minimal rework:

```
progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
```

Answer (score 8):

- This sample was inspired from:

  - http://harmoniccode.blogspot.jp/2011/05/varying-gradients.html
  - http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.jp/2011/06/gradient-translucent-track-jslider.html

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.beans.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class GradientPalletProgressBarDemo {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setOpaque(false);
    progressBar.setUI(new GradientPalletProgressBarUI());

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(progressBar);
    p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Start") {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        SwingWorker<Void,Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void,Void>() {
          @Override public Void doInBackground() {
            int current = 0, lengthOfTask = 100;
            while(current<=lengthOfTask && !isCancelled()) {
              try { // dummy task
                Thread.sleep(50);
              } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
                return null;
              }
              setProgress(100 * current / lengthOfTask);
              current++;
            }
            return null;
          }
        };
        worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new ProgressListener(progressBar));
        worker.execute();
      }
    }));
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new GradientPalletProgressBarDemo().makeUI());
    frame.setSize(320, 240);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
class ProgressListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
  private final JProgressBar progressBar;
  ProgressListener(JProgressBar progressBar) {
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
    this.progressBar.setValue(0);
  }
  @Override public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    String strPropertyName = evt.getPropertyName();
    if("progress".equals(strPropertyName)) {
      progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
      int progress = (Integer)evt.getNewValue();
      progressBar.setValue(progress);
    }
  }
}
class GradientPalletProgressBarUI extends BasicProgressBarUI {
  private final int[] pallet;
  public GradientPalletProgressBarUI() {
    super();
    this.pallet = makeGradientPallet();
  }
  private static int[] makeGradientPallet() {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2  = image.createGraphics();
    Point2D start  = new Point2D.Float(0f, 0f);
    Point2D end    = new Point2D.Float(99f, 0f);
    float[] dist   = {0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f};
    Color[] colors = { Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN };
    g2.setPaint(new LinearGradientPaint(start, end, dist, colors));
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 1);
    g2.dispose();

    int width  = image.getWidth(null);
    int[] pallet = new int[width];
    PixelGrabber pg = new PixelGrabber(image, 0, 0, width, 1, pallet, 0, width);
    try {
      pg.grabPixels();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pallet;
  }
  private static Color getColorFromPallet(int[] pallet, float x) {
    if(x < 0.0 || x > 1.0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter outside of expected range");
    }
    int i = (int)(pallet.length * x);
    int max = pallet.length-1;
    int index = i<0?0:i>max?max:i;
    int pix = pallet[index] & 0x00ffffff | (0x64 << 24);
    return new Color(pix, true);
  }
  @Override public void paintDeterminate(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
    if (!(g instanceof Graphics2D)) {
      return;
    }
    Insets b = progressBar.getInsets(); // area for border
    int barRectWidth  = progressBar.getWidth()  - (b.right + b.left);
    int barRectHeight = progressBar.getHeight() - (b.top + b.bottom);
    if (barRectWidth <= 0 || barRectHeight <= 0) {
      return;
    }
    int cellLength = getCellLength();
    int cellSpacing = getCellSpacing();
    // amount of progress to draw
    int amountFull = getAmountFull(b, barRectWidth, barRectHeight);

    if(progressBar.getOrientation() == JProgressBar.HORIZONTAL) {
      // draw the cells
      float x = amountFull / (float)barRectWidth;
      g.setColor(getColorFromPallet(pallet, x));
      g.fillRect(b.left, b.top, amountFull, barRectHeight);

    } else { // VERTICAL
      //...
    }
    // Deal with possible text painting
    if(progressBar.isStringPainted()) {
      paintString(g, b.left, b.top, barRectWidth, barRectHeight, amountFull, b);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for lesson a about PixelGrabber, learning item of day :-)

Comment: @mKorbel Thanks, I remove unused variable.

Answer (score 4):

You can do either of this way:

```
           UIManager.put("ProgressBar.background", Color.BLACK); //colour of the background    

UIManager.put("ProgressBar.foreground", Color.RED);  //colour of progress bar
    UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionBackground",Color.YELLOW);  //colour of percentage counter on black background    
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionForeground",Color.BLUE);  //colour of precentage counter on red background
```

There is a thread here.
[Setting the colors of a JProgressBar text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480125/setting-the-colors-of-a-jprogressbar-text)

There is a sample demo here at this link as well.
[how to change color progressbar](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/315100/how-to-change-color-progressbar)

Comment: Is this the way to be able to dynamically change the colour of the progress bar itself? I thought this is more of initialisation of the bar to be a particular colour?

Comment: I tried placing the 4 lines of code before the JProgressbar has been initiated but I didn't notice the colour change...

Comment: Does it matter on the OS the app is running on?

Comment: It may matter because default look and feel in Apple is different that Windows

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, is value-dependent "progress" painting not supported. Theoretically, setting the foregound of the progressBar instance dynamically (that is depending on value) is the way to go.

But: the details of progressBar painting are *highly* LAF dependent

- in simple LAFs (like Metal) setting the foreground is fine
- in fully skinnable LAFs (like synth-based LAF) that support per-instance skinning (f.i. Nimbus) you can try to provide a Painter which uses the foreground
- in not-skinnable LAFs there is no way (except overriding the concrete LAF and try to hook into the painting code)

Some snippet:

```
    final JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar();
    // used for Nimbus (beware: just a proof-of-concept - this looks extremely ugly!)
    Painter p = new Painter() {

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics2D g, Object object, int width, int height) {
            JProgressBar bar = (JProgressBar) object;
            g.setColor(bar.getForeground());
            g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        }

    };
    // install custom painter on the bar
    UIDefaults properties = new UIDefaults();
    properties.put("ProgressBar[Enabled].foregroundPainter", p);
    bar.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", properties);

    // simulate progress
    Action action = new AbstractAction("timer") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            bar.setValue(bar.getValue() + 1);
            // change foreground value-dependent
            if (bar.getValue() > 10) {
                bar.setForeground(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer(100, action);
    timer.start();
```